# Dynamic container height in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to dynamically size the height of a container in FlutterFlow? See example below:

[image]

The first post has a container with text and an image. The second has only text. I want to collapse all the unused whitespace in the second container.

Comment: Could you give us a little code?

Comment: Can you include issue reproducible code example

Comment: FlutterFlow's UI components are configured via drag and drop interface - so unfortunately I have no code examples I can share. I checked the documentation and a bunch of tutorials, but no mention of how to handle this use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer on FlutterFlow Discord:

1. Set the 'Height' of the container that wraps the image to null/undefined.
   a) Set the 'Max H' to x% (e.g. 25%).
2. Set the image 'Height' to null/undefined.
   a) Set the Expansion for the image to contracted (the left icon).

This will allow the container to expand or contract based on whether an image is present.

Notes:
The default picsum images cause the image to overflow the container. This problem goes away if I upload images via the 'Upload Media' widget and set photo_url to the path it generates.

Answer (score -1):

if your

```dart
image !=null? ImageWidget():SizeBox()
```